# How to convert byte image from [0,255] to [-1,1] float range in Python for Tensorflow Mobilenet predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, jpeg

I'm an R user, new to both Python and TensorFlow, and have been struggling to get my retrained image classifier to actually make predictions when modifying [label_image.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) for use with Mobilenets.  I've identified the problem and know I need to implement the last line from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/tutorials/image_retraining#other_model_architectures), but I can't figure out how.

> If you're going to be using the Mobilenet models in label_image or
>   your own programs, you'll need to feed in an image of the specified
>   size converted to a float range into the 'input' tensor. Typically
>   24-bit images are in the range [0,255], and you must convert them to
>   the [-1,1] float range expected by the model with the formula (image -
>   128.)/128..

In R I'm used to dealing with JPEGs as 3 dimensional arrays.  If it were in that format I would know what to do, but the image type returned from `tf.gfile.FastGFile("fileName.jpg", 'rb').read()` is `bytes`.  I don't really understand what this is.  Directly applying the formula they give to the image object returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bytes' and 'float'`.  I assume that after I change the range I'll still need it to be in `bytes` format to feed it into the network, but I'm not 100% clear on that either.  Any clarifications on what this object type is and how to work with it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.gfile.FastGfile..read()` returns a binary string, to get image value you have to decode.

```
imagedata = tf.gfile.FastGFile("fileName.jpg", 'rb').read()
img_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(imagedata, dct_method="INTEGER_ACCURATE")
image_standardized = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
image_standardized = tf.clip_by_value(image_standardized, -1.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think in the 3rd line you meant image to be img_decoded, correct?  This does part of what I need but now it's a Tensor object.  How do I get this back to the same kind of binary string it was before?

Comment: yes, it returns the decoded jpeg image, to encode the decoded tensor to binary string again, you can use `tf.image.encode_jpeg(some_image)`

Comment: That was my suspicion, but it gave me a "TypeError: Input 'image' of 'EncodeJpeg' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of uint8."  None of the arguments listed in the API seemed to me obvious fixes for this so I figured I was on the wrong track.

Comment: that's right. after converting it to [-1, 1] range it wont be possible to encode

Answer (score 0):

`bytes` is literally a buffer of raw bytes, which lie in the range [0,255]. You can get the `int` values out by iterating over it. Then you can normalize.

```
image = b'\x20\x30\x40'
normalized = [(x-128.)/128 for x in image]
print(normalized) # [-0.75, -0.625, -0.5]
```